# storage internal hard disk directory not seen

Tags: bash, permissions, hard-drive, files, filesystem

Sorry i'm utterly n00b... i think i have a storage internal hard disk mounted at /media/me/hard_drive

It is not my primary hard drive,i think my primary drive is the SSD i think is mounted at /.

If i do on the bash:

cd /media/me/hard_drive

and then ls i get no output:

```
cd /media/me/hard_drive
ls
stefano@stefano-desktop:/media/me/hard_drive$
```

But i should have actually many files on my hard_drive.
In fact i can reach this folder with gnome ghraphical user interface...files,then other locations, then hard_drive and i can see the subfolders of hard_drive.

If i go with

```
ls /media/me
hard_drive hardrive_1
```

i get hard_drive hardrive_1 subdirectories...

but i don't remember to have ever created subdirectory hard_drive1..

It seems all my files storaged are in hard_drive1...but on gnome i go to this files with files/other locations/hard_drive

Can somebody please explain?

TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can happen if at some point you did not properly unmounted the drive. The automatically created mount point, `/media/me/hard_drive` then does not get deleted. Next time the system tries to mount the drive, it sees that folder already exists and therefore creates another mount point, `/media/me/hard_drive_1`.

Ubuntu automatically creates a mount point for removable drives under `/media/$USER` according to certain rules. The mount point is a folder where the contents of the drive are going to appear after mounting the drive. If the drive has a label, e.g. `hard_drive` in your case, it will use the label as the name of the mount point. Otherwise, it uses the UUID of the partition.

**To solve the issue**

- Remove the drive correctly: right-click in Files, select "Safely remove drive". A notification soon after will indicate when it is safe to unplug the drive. Unplug it physically when this notification appears.
- Remove the `/media/me/hard_drive` mount point. You need administration privileges for that. You can do so with the command `sudo rmdir /media/me/hard_drive`.
- Verify that ``/media/me/`is empty now (or at least does not anymore contain the`/media/me/hard_drive` folder.

Next time you connect the drive, Ubuntu will recreate `/media/me/hard_drive` and you will see your files back again there.

**To prevent the issue from occurring again**

Always carefully unmount the drive using software before physically unplugging it from the computer. You can do that, in standard Ubuntu, by right-clicking the drive in Files (nautilus) then selecting "Safely remove drive".

Comment: Do this answer is OK also for internal hard drive? Do i have to unplug the internal SATA storage hard disk (and then replug)?